# Getting images from twitter-timeline text for iOS with Obj. C

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

In my app I use the STTwitterAPI to represent my tweets. They are arranged in a tableView with a custom cell which include two labels. One for the date (created_at) and one for the content (text). How can I, if they are available in the tweet, load and display the images?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out, that the path to the "media_url" is not readable in one expression. After loaded the file from twitter to a NSDictionary, I thought I can access directly like in php in a form like this:

```
NSDictionary * twitterpost = self.twitterFeed[idx];
NSString *imageURL = twitterpost[[@"entities"][@"media"][0][@"media_url"]];
```

But this doesn't worked and I found this solution:

```
NSDictionary *twitterpost = self.twitterFeed[idx];
NSDictionary *entities = twitterpost[@"entities"];
NSArray *medias = entities[@"media"];
NSDictionary *ImageUrls = medias[0];
NSString *imageURL = ImageUrls[@"media_url"];
```

And with this String I can load the image and display it.

One problem solved, one new. But for this new issue I make, if necessary a separate question.